# Display Google sheet results in Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google form that has question to enter email address and have a Google spreadsheet that has email and attending columns:

Sample of spreadsheet

```
Timestamp   Email Address               Attending 
Jan 02 2020 mernawny1213333@gmail.com   Yes
            msmsmsmsms@gmail.com        No
Jan 20 2020 ssss@gmail.com              Yes
```

What I want is check if the input email address is attending in spreadsheet or no ? - if yes I should display "Yes attending in Jan 02 2020" otherwise "No" - any help in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers for forms which are currently supported are `onOpen` and `onFormSubmit`

I created a script and it is working but the issue is the trigger.

- `onOpen` - when the form is opened for edit (not applicable when filling up form)
- `onFormSubmit` - when the form is already submitted (can't do dialogs/alert due to this error `Error: Cannot call FormApp.getUi() from this context`)

So what I did is when opening/refreshing the page where you edit your form, I trigger the function below:

```
function showPrompt() {
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Please enter email:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var email = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    var ssID = '1B2zmo1IIoE9OdgEZQ36gJN4AQ_WMPoWtW6UrvEt25gc';
    var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
    var dataEmail = sheet.getRange('B2:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
    var found = false;
    dataEmail.forEach(function(item, index){
      if (email == item && sheet.getRange('C' + (index + 2)).getDisplayValue() == 'Yes') {
        found = true;
        ui.alert(email + ' is attending in ' + sheet.getRange('A' + (index + 2)).getDisplayValue());
      }
      if (!found && index == dataEmail.length - 1){
        ui.alert(email + ' is not attending');
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

Make sure to add the function under `triggers`:

[image: triggers]

When the form is opened as edit:

[image: step 1]

Sample Data:

[image: data]

Outputs:

[image: output1]
[image: output2]
[image: output3]

If you prefer using `onFormSubmit`, you can't do alerts/dialogs but you do other things as well. If it's fine, you can try sending email instead.